# Why didnt found the gem when start puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby, puma

I just want deploy my code to server, when I try to start the app on server with this syntax `bin/puma-init.sh start`, I'm getting this error gem not found like this.

```
 [root@arben apps-project]# Puma starting in single mode...
    * Version 3.6.2 (jruby 9.1.5.0 - ruby 2.3.1), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
    * Min threads: 8, max threads: 16
    * Environment: development Could not find tzinfo-1.2.10 in any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. 
! Unable to load application: SystemExit: exit
```

I was checked the gem, its installed and when I'm doing `rails s` its running like normally no problem.

and when I'm doing `bundle install`, there is no problem found too, here the result

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
The dependency pg (~> 0.18.4) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for java but the dependency is only for ruby. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform ruby`.
Using rake 11.2.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.6 (java)
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.6 (java)
Using tzinfo 1.2.10
Using activesupport 4.2.7.1
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.10 (java)
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.4
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.18.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.3
Using actionview 4.2.7.1
Using rack 1.6.13
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.7.1
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 4.2.7.1
Using mini_mime 1.1.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 4.2.7.1
Using activemodel 4.2.7.1
Using active_model_serializers 0.9.0.pre from https://github.com/starqle/active_model_serializers (at starqle@df97f23)
jar-dependencies: spec must be either String or Gem::Specification
Using arel 6.0.4
Using activerecord 4.2.7.1
Using activerecord-jdbc-adapter 1.3.25
Using jdbc-postgres 9.4.1206
Using activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter 1.3.25
Using public_suffix 4.0.7
Using addressable 2.8.1
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using gyoku 1.4.0
Using akami 1.3.1
Using ancestry 2.1.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.4.0.3
Using awesome_print 1.9.2
Using descendants_tracker 0.0.4
Using ice_nine 0.11.2
Using axiom-types 0.1.1
Using bcrypt 3.1.18 (java)
Using rb-fsevent 0.11.2
Using ffi 1.15.5 (java)
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.7.4
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.4.1
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using coercible 1.0.0
Using matrix 0.1.0
Using ruby-rc4 0.1.5
Using combine_pdf 1.0.22
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using connection_pool 2.2.5
Using crack 0.4.5
Using database_cleaner 1.5.3
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using thor 1.2.1
Using railties 4.2.7.1
Using responders 2.4.1
Using warden 1.2.7
Using devise 4.2.1
Using diff-lcs 1.5.0
Using docile 1.3.5
Using dotenv 2.8.1
Using dotenv-rails 2.8.1
Using multi_json 1.15.0
Using dragonfly 1.1.5
Using htmlentities 4.3.4
Using spoon 0.0.6
Using launchy 2.4.3 (java)
Using email_spec 2.1.2
Using equalizer 0.0.11
Using factory_girl 4.7.0
Using factory_girl_rails 4.7.0
Using multipart-post 2.2.3
Using faraday 0.9.2
Using finite_machine 0.11.3
Using friendly_id 5.1.0
Using tilt 2.0.11
Using haml 4.0.7
Using sexp_processor 4.16.1
Using ruby_parser 3.19.1
Using html2haml 2.2.0
Using haml-rails 0.9.0
Using hashdiff 1.0.1
Using hirb 0.7.3
Using socksify 1.7.1
Using httpi 2.5.0
Using jwt 2.3.0
Using libreconv 0.9.5
Using lograge 0.4.1
Using mime-types-data 3.2022.0105
Using mime-types 3.4.1
Using net-ldap 0.16.3
Using nori 2.6.0
Using puma 3.6.2 (java)
Using pundit 1.1.0
Using rack-cors 0.4.1
Using rack-protection 1.5.5
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Using rails 4.2.7.1
Using redis 3.3.5
Using redis-namespace 1.5.3
Using rubyzip 1.3.0
Using roo 2.7.1
Using ruby-ole 1.2.12.2
Using spreadsheet 1.1.9
Using roo-xls 1.0.0
Using rspec-support 3.5.0
Using rspec-core 3.5.4
Using rspec-expectations 3.5.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.5.0
Using rspec 3.5.0
Using rspec-rails 3.5.2
Using rufus-scheduler 3.2.2
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using wasabi 3.7.0
Using savon 2.11.2
Using sentry-raven 2.13.0
Using shoulda-matchers 3.1.3
Using sinatra 1.4.8
Using sidekiq 4.1.4
Using simplecov-html 0.10.2
Using simplecov 0.17.1
Using spring 2.0.2
Using spring-commands-rspec 1.0.4
Using therubyrhino_jar 1.7.6
Using therubyrhino 2.0.5
Using timecop 0.8.1
Using uglifier 3.0.4
Using useragent 0.16.10
Using virtus 1.0.5
Using wicked_pdf 1.1.0
Using will_paginate 3.1.8
Using wisper 1.6.1
Using verp-core 0.0.1 from https://github.com/xxx/verp.git (at master@6057b91)
jar-dependencies: spec must be either String or Gem::Specification
Using verp-ext 0.0.1 from https://github.com/xxx/verp.git (at master@6057b91)
jar-dependencies: spec must be either String or Gem::Specification
Using verp-gateway 0.0.1 from https://github.com/xxx/verp.git (at master@6057b91)
jar-dependencies: spec must be either String or Gem::Specification
Using verp-sap 0.0.1 from https://github.com/xxx/verp.git (at master@6057b91)
jar-dependencies: spec must be either String or Gem::Specification
Using verp 0.0.1 from https://github.com/xxx/verp.git (at master@6057b91)
jar-dependencies: spec must be either String or Gem::Specification
Using webmock 2.1.0
Bundle complete! 26 Gemfile dependencies, 146 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

here my `puma-init.sh`
[image]

here my `puma.rb`
[image]

I was trying uninstall bundler, remove Gemfile.lock and installed again, bundle install again, but the result still same, the app won't started.

any solution to make this `bin/puma-init.sh start` syntax running without problem ?

Comment: Can you show the content of `puma-init.sh` script here ? So that we get better idea about the issue.

Comment: I would investigate why the first line of the output warns you about _Don't run Bundler as root. ..._ Did you install Ruby or Bundler, or did you run Ruby or Bundler as root?

Comment: hi @RahulSingh , I was update my question..

Comment: I dont know why there is warning, but I installed Ruby and Bundler normally just like rvm install jruby-9.1.5.0 and gem install bundler , then do bundle install.. @spickermann

Comment: I can't this see this gem - `tzinfo-1.2.10` on your bundle install, can you run this `bundle info tzinfo-1.2.10` to check its installed? if not installed please install this, because you were getting error due to this only.

Comment: @RahulSingh there is line `Using tzinfo 1.2.10` on bundle install, I;m getting error when running `bundle info tzinfo-1.2.10`, but if I run `bundle info tzinfo` the result are like this
` tzinfo (1.2.10)
 Summary: Daylight savings aware timezone library
 Homepage: https://tzinfo.github.io
 Path: /usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-9.1.5.0@job_verp/gems/tzinfo-1.2.10`